# Invoke a method with a named parameter through reflection

Tags: scala

Say I define the following case class:

```
case class A(x: Int, y: String, s: Double)
```

and I want to be able dynamically call the copy method via reflection to achieve something like the following:

```
val a1 = A(1, "hello", 2.3)
val a2 = a1.copy(y = "goodbye")  // Do this with reflection???
```

Is it possible to do the copy via reflection?

Thanks
Des

Comment: I think the problem will be finding the other parameters, the default values for reflection.

Comment: Well I do not think `a1.copy(y = "goodbye") ` would be possible. Though `a1.copy("y","goodbye") ` should be fairly simple. But a solution based on macros should be the best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment Scala's runtime reflection library doesn't provide a convenient way to invoke methods with named/default arguments. Current API only allows reflective calls to methods when the user explicitly provides arguments for all parameters in their declaration order. Please submit an issue to our bug tracker, and I'll be happy to look into it.

Comment: The ticket is https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8393 , but (as of 2023) it hasn't progressed.